# WebDriver NodeJS Instantiate IE Driver with Capabilities: introduceFlakinessByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings(ignoreSettings)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to instantiate a driver session using the IE capabilities to ignore the protected mode settings in Internet Explorer, but I am unsure of the syntax.

I have tried:

```
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.ie().introduceFlakinessByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings(true).build();

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.ie().introduceFlakinessByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings, true.build();

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.ie().ignoreProtectedModeSettings(true).build();

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.ie().introduceFlakinessByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings(true).build();

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities({ "browserName": "ie" }, {"ignoreProtectedModeSettings": "true"}).build();

 var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities({ "browserName": "ie" }, {"introduceFlakinessByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings": "true"}).build();
```

Thus far none have worked. What is the correct sytax for this in Javascript? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

After having the same problem and going through the code for `selenium-webdriver`, I found the following to work:

```
const Capabilities = require('selenium-webdriver/lib/capabilities').Capabilities;
let capabilities = Capabilities.ie();
capabilities.set('ignoreProtectedModeSettings', true);
const driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(capabilities).build();
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks a ton - I had basically given up. Any ideas on how to ignore Zoom Settings? I've been struggling with that as well. Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't have that issue, but it should be something like `capabilities.set('ignoreZoomSetting', true)`
If this solved your issue, please mark it solved, thanks!